# Using common mode inductance or differential mode inductance in a power circuit?

Tags: surge-protection

The question derives from [my last question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/648150/is-a-surge-a-common-mode-signal-or-a-differential-mode-signal).

When the power circuit is powered up, there is surge because of the input capacitor. The surge is a differential mode signal. So to reduce the surge, why not use a differential mode inductance? Why is a common mode inductance often used?

I used LTspice to check the effect. The waveforms are as follows. It thinks that the common mode inductance is better because the current peak is smaller and there isn't a oscillation.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Both circuits can be reduced to a single L and C in series.  The CM version has less equivalent inductance so is better damped with respect to whatever ESR you've set in the circuit (please show them on all V, C, L).

Comment: Where is the difference between common mode and differential source "voltages" ? See this ? https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/586646/is-this-explanation-of-a-common-mode-choke-correct/645911#645911 you need at least 3 points.

Comment: The input capacitor current surge IS NOT common mode.

Comment: @Andy Sorry, I've made a typo. I will edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps, this can help ... See also [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/653161/surge-suppresor-design-dm-cm-chokes-and-resistor-is-series-with-varistor/653517#653517).

Behavior of coupled inductors (CMode & DMode, just change coupling from 1 to -1).

[image]

[image]