# Common mode choke and inductor for inverter circuit

Tags: inductor, inverter

I am building an inverter that uses an H-Bridge and PWM to generate something that should get close to a sine wave. My original design only included a common mode choke, however now that I am doing looking at my design again (still before manufacturing) and learned more about how those chokes work I noticed, that there will most likely be no inductance at all due to the common mode choke getting equal current on both windings causing them to cancel out. Is that correct? So the choke will only filter noise that shouldn't be there.

To solve it I want to add 2 additional inductors, however, I am running out of space on my PCB and the only way I could do it would be to add one inductor on one side of the choke and the other one on the other side, like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f38nrh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The "transformer" is the common mode choke in my case. Are there any downsides in this approach or is this perfectly fine? I assume it is fine because the order shouldn't matter, but I am not sure.

Comment: @winny Yes, I corrected it. Thanks!

Comment: A CM choke does the opposite of what you say. You said this: *I noticed, that there will most likely be no inductance at all due to the common mode choke getting equal current on both windings causing them to cancel out. Is that correct?* and that is incorrect.

Comment: @Andyaka Maybe I didn't describe it correctly: On the schematics above, imagine the 2 inductors are not there. On the left is my H-Bridge, on the right is my load. Wouldn't in that case both windings cancel each other out so under normal conditions the inductance is close to 0 so I will have a hard time getting a sine wave out of it?

Comment: The currents need to be equal magnitude and opposite direction to get zero inductance.

Comment: And that's the case if I connect it as shown above. So I could either connect one side of it in the opposite direction so they don't cancel themselves out or add additional inductors.

Comment: So the question is whether the CMC has DM inductance as well?  It does: it's called "leakage inductance".

Comment: You are talking about common mode current when you say equal current on both sides and that produces inductance.

Comment: It would help a lot, if you added the switches and load to your schematic. Then one could tell if/where inductors or CMC make any sense

Comment: Review this, please https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/648328/using-common-mode-inductance-or-differential-mode-inductance-in-a-power-circuit/648348#648348