# Surge suppresor design - DM, CM chokes and resistor is series with varistor

Tags: inductor, surge-protection, common-mode-choke

While designing a surge suppressor, I came up with an online schematic where they use a differential mode choke and a common mode choke.

I put one toroid choke coil as the differential mode choke.

Here's my schematic:
[image]

The input and output should be close to 250V max at 50Hz (AC). For the varistors however, I have seen most surge protectors use 14D471K.

Is it possible that the inductors induce some spikes to the circuit connected to `OUT N` and `OUT L` if loads are connected and disconnected while the circuit is on?

Also, I put two 0.1 ohms resistor in series to the output. It seems as if the varistors have some resistance even though it acts as a short circuit. Is it worth putting the resistors series to the output?

**EDIT**

The circuit should be connected directly to 250VAC @60Hz. The output I expect is also similar, but the max can go up to 300V. 14D471K suits this perfectly.

When it comes to the the surges that I want it to protect against, is the power line surges coming from various disturbances. It should also protect against Electro-Magnetic Interference.

On the most extreme side, I want it to protect with high surges from lightning - although this is a huge challenge both to test the circuit with such spikes and also protect them, but it should at least somehow manage protect devices.

Comment: Before something like this is designed, I would recommend writing/detailing a specification that explains what surges and levels the filter is expected to deal with. Then I would simulate those surges and see how the proposed design behaves.

Comment: In light of your "EDIT", I guess what @Andyaka means, that you specify **quantifiable** goals (e.g. from the 61000-4-X EMI classes), with specified surge impedances and then put them into a sim tool. You will see what voltages and currents your components will have to deal to a pretty accurate degree. Then you can select according components.

Comment: There are four fuses, what was this based on??

Comment: The first one is a glass fuse (which I think I can remove), the second one is a resettable fuse which resets itself after the circuit is overloaded. The third one is a thermal fuse - it trips when the varistors get hot or blows up - it should be sandwiched between the varistors with a thermal pad. The last fuse towards the load is also a resettable fuse just for failsafe. The circuit overall can put 2 amps max to protect electronic devices like computers, laptops, etc.

Comment: _"Is it possible that the inductors induce some spikes"_ If your capacitors on both sides of your DM choke are too small and you have a big load step, then yes. For most designs, your C end up more than large enough to not have that problem. Please simulate your circuit.

Comment: <<< On the most extreme side, I want it to protect with high surges from lightning >>>    one need 3 wires  (ground also) ... https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/648328/using-common-mode-inductance-or-differential-mode-inductance-in-a-power-circuit

Comment: Lol, lightning safe? Really? How is it exposed to lightning? 3 fuses in a row might not make it better per se.

Answer (score 1):

For reference, here are two cases of simulation (Lightning pulse 1.2 us-50 us-100 kV).
Coupling (1, -1).

[image]

[image]

And when "all" is "ok" for components values (L6 and kc), we should be ok with v(VL1,VL2).

Here, we should add VDR or something like, to limit overvoltage on VL1 and VL2 points, referred to ground.

[image]